# Vaadin Widget return value

Tags: cookies, push, vaadin, rpc

I'm creating a Vaadin application that has push enabled and I need to get/set cookies from the client-side (via widget). Because returning anything else than void in RPC is not allowed, I have problems to return the data.

I tried to use the Shared State of the Widget, but the data seems to be handled in an asychronous way.

How can I get the data from the client - which options do i have?

Thank you for any reply!

Answer (score 0):

SharedState is read-only on the client-side. When you want to get data from the client to the server, you need to use server RPC. Normally, it would be enough that you read the cookie's value from the shared state object on the server, but in case the state doesn't have the value (eg. you are using a persistent cookie and you want to read the cookie value when the application is initialized), you need to read the cookie using javascript and then send the value to the server using RPC. On the server, the component should then update the shared state's value.